# ion-searchbar as a tab component IONIC 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

My Ionic 2 App is having 5 tabs:-

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="ios-blicon-home" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Categories" tabIcon="ios-blicon-category"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="ios-blicon-search" (click)="startsearch()"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Bookmark" tabIcon="ios-blicon-bookmark"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Me" tabIcon="ios-blicon-me"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I have four component and one is a search tab where I want to pop a seachbar (ion-searchbar) whenever clicked and it can trigger a function on submit.

I am not sure how to do this, please suggest me.

Thank you..!!

Comment: do you need a new page with search tab?

Comment: no I am looking to have a pop up search bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Tabs component, use `ionSelect` event instead of `click`

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="ios-blicon-home" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Categories" tabIcon="ios-blicon-category"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="ios-blicon-search" (ionSelect)="startsearch()"></ion-tab><!-- use ionSelect -->
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Bookmark" tabIcon="ios-blicon-bookmark"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Me" tabIcon="ios-blicon-me"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="showSearch"></ion-searchbar>
```

In the component side have a class variable:

```
showSearch:boolean=false;
startsearch(){
 this.showSearch = ! this.showSearch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create another page with searchbar - say `SearchPage` component.

And you have to give the `[root]` for that tab to that component.

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="ios-blicon-search"></ion-tab>
```

In your tabs.ts - `tab3Root = "SearchPage"`.

Now, whatever searching functionality you need, will be in this SearchPage component. Refer [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/) for how to implement searchbar.